# Create new Response using Survey Monkey REST API V3

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to create new responses using SurveyMonkey API, I am following this document provided by SurveyMonkey: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/?shell#collectors-id-responses

and here is the request I am making:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/{suvey_id}/responses -d  '{"custom_variables":{"custvar_1": "one", "custvar_2": "two"},"response_status": "completed","custom_value": "custom identifier for the response","date_created": "2015-10-06T12:56:55+00:00","ip_address": "127.0.0.1", "pages": [{"id": "{page_id}","questions": [{"answers": [{"text": "Sample Text Response"}], "id": "{questions_id}"}, {"answers": [{"choice_id": "{choice_id}"}], "id": "{questions_id}"}]}]}'
```

and I am getting a 404 response:

```
{"error": {"docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes", "message": "There was an error retrieving the requested resource.", "id": "1020", "name": "Resource Not Found", "http_status_code": 404}}
```

I have verified values of "choice_id", "questions_id", "page_id" and "survey_id", all of them are correct but I am still getting a 404, I am completely stuck down with this issue, any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a response on a specific collector. So the request needs to be to `/v3/collectors/{collector_id}/responses`

Comment: @GeneralKandalaft Thanks! you are right. They have mentioned incorrect URL in the example.